# when does the content in an iframe load?

Tags: html

```
<iframe src="http://someramdomlink/wxy" 
style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="myiFrame"
scrolling="no" frameborder="1"  height="60px" width="468px"></iframe>
```

---

Question 1)
I am placing an iframe in a webpage,So when does the link in  the iframe load? 
Is it already loaded in the server or is it loaded when the user opens the particular page with the iframe?
Question2)
Also I am placing an iframe within an iframe,I mean I am placing an iframe in the page http://some-ramdom-link.com/xyz Will this iframe also be loaded?Does it work that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is loaded when requested by browser, not already loaded in server.
2. Yes you can have an iframe within an iframe